# Why my Amz EC2 server downs everyday for few minutes? Errors 503 and 502. It's a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

I don't know which error causes the problem. When I see, the server is down with the error 503. In Google Chrome log, I have the following error:

```
503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity
```

While the server is down, I can't get to connect via SSH to see the error log. After few minutes the server works and I am go to the nginx error log.

In the log, I have common errors, like:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Attachment with 'id'=4240)
```

I know how to solve and I think that this errors is not the problem.

But I have this error too:

```
Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
Process (pid=31880, group=/home/ubuntu/........./current/public) no longer exists! Detaching it from the pool.
```

I think that it is the problem, but I looked in the internet and the causes and solutions do not appear to solve the problem.

This problem happens after I created a Load Balancer and use HTTPS.
Before, this problem never happens.

About my server and app:

```
Amazon Ec2 instance;
Using Classic Load Balancer (with Amazon Certificate Manager in https port);
Using Route 53;
Don't using Elastic IP;
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
ruby -v: 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v: Rails 4.2.3
nginx -v: nginx/1.8.0
passenger -v: Phusion Passenger version 5.0.10
```

Load Balancer Health Check is set up like this:

```
Ping Target 
HTTP:80/index.html
Timeout 5 seconds
Interval    30 seconds
Unhealthy threshold 5
Healthy threshold   5
```

Health Check Information:

I get this print in the Load Balancer MONITORING tab. Is the **Unhealthy Hosts (Count)**. Why my host was unhealthy?

[image]

Comment: 502 generally means you are getting more requests than the backend server can handle. This could be generated by the load balancer to backend servers or nginx to passenger.

Comment: @datasage Thanks your answer. I dont know how to see the request in the Load Balancer OR change the requests limit. In nginx either. Do you know? I am going to search in Google based in your post information.

Comment: The metrics on the load balancer will determine if the error is coming from the load balancer or backend. If you get an unhealthy host, that means the health check has failed.

Comment: @datasage Hmm, thanks. Do you know what cause a health check fail?

Comment: Could be anything, likely something to do with nginx crashing or getting more requests than it can handle. Your health check looks fairly simple. Is that a static HTML page? or is it routed to something in Ruby?

Comment: @datasage All pages is routed in Ruby. There's no static pages. Your questions open my mind and I am going to keep look for a solution. Thanks!

Comment: then the issue is like related to passenger in some way. Could be crashing or unavailable for some other reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

In my case, the problem was in the assets precompile task.
I have a lot of assets in my app and when I did the deploy with capistrano, it exhausts the server.

In other side, sometimes, the assets was precompiled after the deploy, during the page load. But this task is very slowly, and returns the errors 502, 503 and 504.

It causes the servers down to, because the CPU utilization goes to 100%, the average latency is going higher too.

To solve, I removed the `assets precompile task` from Capistrano. I precompile the assets in my locally PC and send all of them to GIT branch MASTER. When I run `cap production deploy`, the precompile taks will not run. More details in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998095/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-rails-to-precompile-assets-on-production).

I did some changes in my Load Balancer Health Check settings:

```
Ping Target HTTP:80/elb/index.html (I created in pubic folder this folder and file)
Timeout 5 seconds
Interval    30 seconds
Unhealthy threshold 2
Healthy threshold   10

Idle timeout: 65 seconds (equal my nginx timeout)
```

With this I hope the task `assets precompile` never more runs on the server.