# Is there a way to prevent rails to precompile assets on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-ec2, deployment, capistrano3

I have a lot of assets in my project. The precompile task in the server is very slow and exhaust the host (CPU utilization 100%, high average latency).

My idea is to precompile all assets in my localhost and send to GIT (master) all files already precompiled.

In the deploy action (`cap production deploy`), avoid the precompile task and in the server, prevent any precompile task.

The server uses the already precompiled files sended via `capistrano`, available in GIT.

Is it possible? If yes, how to do?
If no, there's another solution to avoid server precomile assets?

Below my configs:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'capistrano-faster-assets', '~> 1.0', group: :development
```

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/faster_assets'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
other assets configs in this file is commented
```

**Environment info**

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)
ruby -v: ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]
rails -v: 4.2.3
nginx -v: nginx/1.8.0
passenger -v: 5.0.10
```

If you need more information, tell me on the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer:

Replace

```
require 'capistrano/rails'
```

with

```
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
```

## Why this works:

When you require `capistrano/rails`, you are really including the following ([source](https://github.com/capistrano/rails/blob/master/lib/capistrano/rails.rb)):

```
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
```

Each of these can be included separately to get just those pieces of functionality. Per the docs: https://github.com/capistrano/rails#usage

Comment: Hello @will_in_wi, thanks your answer. As I see, in the `cap production deploy`, the assets precompile will not occour. Then I have to precompile the assets locally, send to `git master` and after do the deploy, correct?

Comment: Correct. If I understood correctly, you want to precompile your assets locally, commit them to master, and then have Capistrano skip precompilation, since the precompiled assets are already committed. My answer shows you how to skip precompilation.

Comment: Thanks the explanation. I will to test tomorrow, when I am going to deploy some changes. Do you know if is a good idea to change the `config.assets.compile = true` to `false` in `config/environments/production.rb`?

Comment: Yes man, your solution works fine! Now I do the `rake assets precompile` in the local machine and send to `git master` all assets already compiled. I changed the `Capfile` as you suggested and the deploy not run the `precompile`. I changed the `config.assets.compile` to FALSE in `config/environments/production.rb` Thanks!